# How to set space for PDA that store a Vec of structs in data

Tags: anchor

I'm having this pda account to store data in program so how can I set the space correctly?

```
#[derive(Clone, AnchorSerialize, AnchorDeserialize)]
pub struct MarketItem {
    item_id: u128,
    owner: Option<Pubkey>,
    price: u128,
    sold: bool,
    gacha: bool,
}

#[account]
pub struct State {
    pub map: Vec<MarketItem>,
    pub item_ids: u128,
    pub item_sold: u128,
    pub owner: Pubkey,
    pub listing_price: u128,
    pub initialized: bool,
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct InitState<'info> {
    /// CHECK:
    #[account(init, payer = user, space = 9999999999999)]
    pub state_account: Account<'info, State>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub user: Signer<'info>, // admin
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by "correctly"?

Comment: So you mean I just set the space as 9999999999999 will be no problem right?

Comment: pda is also a regular account. the only difference is it is owned by a program

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Accounts are buffers where you store the data. when you initialize an account you specify the size of this buffer. Maximum size if it has not changed recently is 10 mb. so you need to precalculate how much space you would need.

[From space reference table](https://book.anchor-lang.com/anchor_references/space.html)

[image]

this tells you what takes how much space.

> In addition to the space for the account data, you have to add 8 to
> the space constraint for Anchor's internal discriminator

this is why in many contract codes you see `8+32` syntax. that 8 is for the discriminator

Answer (score 0):

As other answers mentioned you can add the u128 (16 bytes each), Pubkey (32 bytes), and bools (1 byte each).

To avoid dealing with Vec and its 4-byte overhead, it's often easier to store a slice on chain and dictate the size, e.g. map: [MarketItem; 4]